# Did Fidel Castro ever make this prediction?

Tags: politics, quotes, fidel-castro

[The Bimini Times](https://www.facebook.com/biminitimes?fref=photo) just put out this [pretty interesting and prophetic Castro quote](https://www.facebook.com/biminitimes/photos/a.974456962564319.1073741977.674513729225312/1049920788351269/?type=1&permPage=1),

> The US will come to talk to us when they have a black president and the world has a Latin American Pope. - Fidel Castro 1973

[image: Fidel Castro says the above.]

I've also seen it [on twitter](https://twitter.com/cubasolidarity/status/609413925923364864),

[image: Another picture with the same alleged Fidel quote]

Comment: The author of the article is Pedro Jorge Solans. Argentinian Poet and writer. The article is also available here: http://www.cubasindical.cu/news.php?readmore=795 , dated 24 Apr 2015. The facebook page of the Author is https://www.facebook.com/solanspedro I suppose the statement is not invented at all, though it would be nice to ask him on his facebook page, if he still has a transcription of that interview.

Comment: Incidentally, Snopes has had a look at this claim, and decided that it's false. http://m.snopes.com/fidel-castro-prophecy-quote/ - Snopes isn't a good enough source for an answer, but it's still worth a read.

Comment: I was going to say, that almost reads like a "When pigs fly and Hell freezes over" kind of quote, more than a prediction.

Answer (score -11, accepted):

[This source has already researched this answer](http://maoistrebelnews.com/2015/06/18/on-the-psychic-powers-of-fidel-castro/). They claim, and cite, the original quote being

> “Estados Unidos vendrá a dialogar con nosotros cuando tenga un Presidente negro y haya en el mundo un Papa latinoamericano”.

Which would make the quote correct. They conclude that context as a prophecy is incorrect because Fidel was referring to the embargo ending not merely Cuba talking to the USA. And, further, that even if the embargo ended it wouldn't be because of the *"anti-bourgeois position of the president and the Pope"*.

Comment: If you follow the references, they point to user's comments on a blog written in May 2015. The only extra information they add is they claim the comments were made to a journalist Brian Davis. I don't see this as a definitive answer, but just a repeat of the claim.

Answer (score 18):

All references about this quote are recent in Internet (after Latin-american Pope and black president facts). It can be found using Google's date range. So it's very likely that these statements were invented. The trusted link about [this story](http://www.clarin.com/mundo/Fidel-Castro-Cuba-EE-UU-asombrosa-prediccion-1973_0_1399060294.html) is in Clarin, a big newspaper in Argentina. The [original source](http://www.eldiariodecarlospaz.com/mundo/2015/3/10/cuba-atraviesa-tiempos-cambios-bloqueo-9988.html) is from a small newspaper in Argentina at March,10,2015. An English journalist "Bryan Davis" is the alleged asker. No information about him can be found.

Comment: This is at best a guess, since Google might not have covered the initial citation as it did not become widely spread at that time. The alleged date of the citation was before Google was founded after all.

Comment: 1973 indeed predates the founding of Google, but Google News has access to digitized archives of many newspapers in English and other languages. Also, it is highly likely that a quote like this would have left at least some trace in the online universe in the past two decades. That's why I agree with @PauloBuchsbaum, the fact that all actual references on the Internet date from the past few months is strongly suggestive of a hoax. I also don't seem to find any relevant references to a journalist named Brian/Bryan Davis.

Comment: There's plenty of info if you equate Brian Davis with Neil Brian Davis, who closely matches the profile. He was Australian but worked for an English company about the time, as well as with American papers.

Comment: If this quote were real, it likely would have made the rounds on the Internet during Obama's run for the Democratic primary in 2007, and again as soon as Pope Francis was named. People would have been speculating "Does this mean Cuba/US relations are about to change?"